# Parse API push notification, open app page on play store

Tags: android, parse-platform, push-notification

So on are our app we have Parse API, to send push notification and manage backend stuff, we are sending and `update the app` notificaiton bt clicking the notification it opens the APP, we would like it to open the store page for our APP, is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

i have used this code so far.You can check if the Google Play Store app is installed and, if this is the case, you can use the "market://" protocol. just write your code instead from where you try to open your app actvity from notification panel.

```
final String my_package_name = "........."  // <- HERE YOUR PACKAGE NAME!!
String url = "";

try {
    //Check whether Google Play store is installed or not:
    this.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("com.android.vending", 0);

    url = "market://details?id=" + my_package_name;
} catch ( final Exception e ) {
    url = "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + my_package_name;
}


//Open the app page in Google Play store:
final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: please accept answer if you seems to right my answer.thanks.